# Es posible crear carpetas y archivos desde una web local en windows

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy creando una página básica html localmente en mi pc, me interesa saber cómo puedo lograr crear carpetas y archivos desde esa web y alojarlas obviamente en el mismo pc (Windows), y a la misma vez como eliminarlas desde ahí...
Usando Javascript, sin usar Xampp o cosas así, todo localmente.
¿Que solución puedo estudiar?

Comment: Podrías dar un ejemplo más concreto de lo que querés hacer? No se entiende muy bien. Lo que si te puedo decir, es que si querés poder crear carpetas, necesitás un lenguaje que corra del lado del servidor. Con JS desde el lado del cliente no vas a poder. Con lo cual vas a necesitar XAMPP o similar.

Comment: Con JavaScritp  solamente no podrás. Con Node se puede crear. O bien con PHP  con ` mkdir`. Más info: https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.mkdir.php y con Node... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13696148/node-js-create-folder-or-use-existing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para hacer algo asi, javascript no te sirve, ya que javascript por motivos de seguridad no tiene acceso a los archivos del sistema, jQuery tiene algunas funciones que te permiten leer la data de por ejemplo algunos archivos, pero nada mas de ahi, si lo que requieres es eliminar, modificar e insertar informacion te recomiendo que aprendas un poco de PHP.

Por otro lado con respecto a que requieres una solucion que no use xampp, lastimosamente PHP solo corre del lado del servidor, por lo que debes usar obligatoriamente xampp u algun otro server local para hacer cosas asi.

Para darte una idea de como podrias hacer la modificacion, añadir o eliminar paginas web de tus directorios de la pagina principal, una de las cosas que podrias hacer es crear un "formulario maestro", al cual solo puedas acceder tu, y mediante el y la data traida por php, que te muestre que archivos tienes, con que extension y hasta el nombre (Todo esto es posible con php), de acuerdo a esto, que puedas seleccionar por ejemplo un archivo y eliminarlo, y en caso de querer editarlo, pues es un poco mas complejo, lo de crear carpetas tampoco es problema, por lo que aqui te dejo algunos ejemplos de funciones de php que podrias requerir en PHP:

[mkdir](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.mkdir.php)
mkdir (Permite crear un directorio)

[chdir](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.chdir.php)
Permite cambiar de directorio (Los datos, carpetas y archivos que encuentres seran ahora los de la ruta que especificaste a los que apuntara php)

[rmdir](https://secure.php.net/manual/es/function.rmdir.php)
rmdir (Remueve un directorio entero)

[file_put_contents](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.file-put-contents.php)
file_put_contents (Escribe informacion en un fichero o lo crea donde se requiere)

[fopen](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.fopen.php)
fopen (lee informacion de un fichero o una URL)

[fclose](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.fclose.php)
fclose (Cuando usamos fopen dejamos un puntero abierto al archivo que abrimos, fclose sirve para cerrar este puntero)

Comment: Por otro lado, te recomiendo bastante el que aprendas PHP, ya que pese a que parece muy complejo, enrealidad es facil de usar y DEMASIADO POTENTE, sirve para muchas cosas.